# What can I do to fix this onestep checkout / paypal express problem?

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-express, onestepcheckout

Here is the problem:

at this page: http://www.domain.com/onestepcheckout/
The customer fills out the fields on the onestep checkout page, select their country as "United States" from the drop down menu, which displays a new dropdown list called "County" which contains all of the states in the US.

The customer picks one of the states, chooses their shipping method, selects paypal as the payment method and then clicks "Place order now" button.

Instead of going to the paypal website to complete the payment, the customer is redirected back to http://www.domain.com/checkout/cart/

The checkout works correctly when using other countries which do not have a dropdown for "county" / state.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Enable debug mode in Magento PayPal configuration. Then check `paypal.log` in `var/log`

Comment: [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10736
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error

Comment: It would appear that the county/state and zip code would not validate. I have tried it again using a real US address and I am able to get through to paypal payment gateway.

Comment: Try adding one for these, https://phptalks.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/valid-us-address-format-or-valid-us-address-for-developer-testing-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the state and zip code would not validate.

I have tried it again using a real US address. I am now able to get through to paypal payment gateway.